# Issue with inverting sparse matrix pylab

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I try to do the following

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
import scipy as s
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.sparse as l
from plot import Graph3DSolution
import numpy.linalg as lin

currentSol=s.sparse.linalg.inv(I-C)*A*lastSol
```

Im missing out some code but the issue is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "explict1wave.py", line 62, in <module>
    currentSol=s.sparse.linalg.inv(I-C)*A*lastSol
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linalg'

Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
im>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.14.0'
>>>
```

I look up the documentation and it seems these libraries existed since .12 . I dont know what the issue is, but im sure its something simple im not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import scipy as s
>>> s.sparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sparse'
>>> 
>>> from scipy.sparse import linalg
>>> linalg.inv
<function inv at 0x19b1758>
>>>
```

General [recommendations for importing functions from scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/api.html) .

On a side note, best avoid star imports. These `from scipy import *`, `from numpy import *` are not recommended and not needed here. Same for `import scipy as s`.